# jQuery deferred always method

Tags: jquery, jquery-deferred

I need to do something when an ajax request is completed, irrespective of it's failure or success. I am using jQuery deferred objects "always" method for this.

My question is inside "always" method how do I determine if it's called because service request failed or succeeded

Comment: Of course, this brings up the question of why not put the code for handling success in the `done()` and the failure part in the `error()` and the shared in `always()` (or even call the same method from both fail and succeed.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**complete**

```
Type: Function( jqXHR jqXHR, String textStatus )
```

A function to be called when the request finishes (after *success* and *error* callbacks are executed). The function gets passed two arguments: The jqXHR (in jQuery 1.4.x, XMLHTTPRequest) object and a string categorizing the status of the request (*"success"*, *"notmodified"*, *"error"*, *"timeout"*, *"abort"*, or *"parsererror"*). **As of jQuery 1.5**, the *complete* setting can accept an array of functions. Each function will be called in turn.

ref: [jQuery.ajax()](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/)

Comment: You are right but your answer isn't readable formatted that way.

Comment: I tried to match the formatting of the reference.  Unfortunately, I don't know how to get SO to do monospace text with gray background.